# GeoPortal - A database Reference has not been configured for connection Tag

Tags: oracle-dbms, xml, geoportal, configuration

I've followed the [instructions on setting up](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Installation-Version-1.2.5) to a tee. I am using Oracle as a database. My database structure has been setup.

I receive the following error message when I try to search for anything:

```
Could not get a csw search engine: Did not get key = local in repository
 com.esri.gpt.framework.context.ConfigurationException: A databaseReference has not been 
configured for connectionTag:
```

When I login, regardless of what credentials I use, it displays "Welcome!" in green, althoug the login hasn't actually happened.

In my gpt.xml file, I have made the following changes:

```
<interactiveMap
    jsapiUrl=http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.3m
    apServiceUrl=”http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer”
    mapServiceType="dynamic"
    geometryServiceUrl="http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer"
    locatorUrl="http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Streets_US/GeocodeServer"
    locatorSingleFieldParameter="City"
    />
```

I commented out LDAP authentication, and opted for simple. I changed the U/N and P/W for this example.

```
<simpleAdapter>
        <account username="exampleUseName" password="examplePassword" encrypted="false"/>
        <roles>
            <role key="gptRegisteredUser"/>
            <role key="gptPublisher"/>
            <role key="gptAdministrator"/>
        </roles>
</simpleAdapter>
```

My question: What does this error message mean? What haven't I configured?

EDIT: Checked the Tomcat logs and found this:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL '*connection string*'
```

Answer (score 1):

With my experience with Geoportal Server I have noticed that when I don't comment out simple and LDAP authentication , then I am able to log-in correctly.  It might be a bug, but try uncommenting the LDAP authentication...by the looks of it, it appears as if its a DB connection issue. make sure that your ports are correct in the geoportal.xml file and that you have the proper drivers.

Comment: May be onto something, check my updated post.

Comment: looks like you don't have the correct jdbc driver or incorrect path.  see page 28.   https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/GeoportalServer_InstallationGuide_1_2_4.pdf

Comment: Geoffrey, your answer was partially correct and was part of my problem! My URL string was not in the correct format, however, when I changed "userName" to "user" in geoportal.xml... it worked! If you update your answer with this bit of information, I'll mark it as correct. I can see this helping a lot of people.